# Session Variables in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Can someone explain where session variables are held?

I have added some session variables in header.php in the controller, for example:

```
$this->session->data['day']=date("d",strtotime($row['startdate']));
```

This works when loading the site, and when I click on a product, all the variables are gone, except for the `[language]`, `[currency]` and `[cart]` which are set by Opencart.

I guess there is another file or controller file where I set the variables, or where `[language]`, `[currency]` and `[cart]` are set but I cannot find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try maybe catalog/languages/en.php or something like that? catalog/controller/languages/en.php. I'm out so I can't check just now

Comment: Peter. I think you may be close with that one, but english.php is not the file. If you do have time later, I would appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Session values are not set in a file. If you want to set a session variable, use

```
$this->session->data['variable_name_here'] = 'data value here';
```

and to retrieve the value you just access

```
$this->session->data['variable_name_here']
```

For example, to echo it use

```
echo $this->session->data['variable_name_here'];
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is which file are these variables held in;

( [language] => en [currency] => USD [cart] => Array ( ) )

I set this;
$this->session->data['day']=date("d",strtotime($row['startdate'])); in header.php which works fine when you load the site, but the variables disappear from the session when clicking on a product.

Comment: header.php is loaded for every page, so its not possible for the variables to disappear unless you've done them in an odd way. Note that $this->data is localised, therefore its not passed from the header to the product template

Comment: if i get your question right then u are far and out of get an answer, the cart is a final class set in system/library/cart.php
the language and currency are retrieved from the DB every they are needed, and by the way dont use $this (this is silly) $this returns a pointer to the class you are in wich is inherited from the controller class in the controller.php file take a closer look about how it is working you will know what to do,

Answer (score 3):

Here I would save the variables into a session:

```
public function receive() {
    $this->session->data['guest_name'] = $this->request->post['name'];
    $this->session->data['guest_address'] = $this->request->post['address'];
}
```

Now in `catalog/controller/checkout/guest.php` at `index` method check for that session variables and if set, store the value in the `$this->data` array for presenting to the template:

```
if(isset($this->session->data['guest_name'])) { // it is enough to check only for one variable and only if it is set
    $this->data['guest_name'] = $this->session->data['guest_name'];
    $this->data['guest_address'] = $this->session->data['guest_address'];
}
```

After that You can simply echo these values in Your template (still checking whether exists):

```
<?php if(isset($guest_name)) { ?>
<div><?php echo $guest_name . ' - ' . $guest_address; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Now You should be done while avoiding any `undefined variable` notices...

Answer (score 2):

There is no file that held the session variables.
Open cart session are created by using "system/library/Session.php". You can create session like this in open cart.

```
<?php
     $this->session->data['session_name'] = 'session value';
?>
```

Now you can call this session in any where in open cart like this.

```
<?php
     echo $this->session->data['session_name'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i bit late but the main class which handle the sessions is in the system/library/session.php, which have public variable $data and handling the $_SESSION in the constructor.
so what ever you put in the $this->session->data it merge.

Hope it will be beneficial.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

/system/library/customer.php does contain $this->session->data['customer_id'];